# plink ssh as root, access denied

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I'm trying to connect to a server via plink. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\>plink -ssh -pw password root@server-name
Using username "root".
Access denied
```

My `sshd_config` file contains `PermitRootLogin yes`, even though that's the default value, just to be sure. Is there some other configuration I need to set to allow this type of connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post or check contents of the log probably found at `/var/log/auth.log`.
Another question would be if you have a password added for your root account?
Otherwise you can try and set this using `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: There is no auth.log anywhere. (Used `find / -name auth.log`). In `/var/log`, the only files that were updated were `/var/log/btmp` and `/var/log/secure`. However, I figured my problem out. I'm pretty pissed about it too. The password contains special characters, which were messing up the command. I fixed it by surrounding the password with double-quotes.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because your suggestion to check the contents of the log helped me arrive at my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My password contained special characters (!@#$%^). I needed to add double-quotes around them to get it to not complain. Silly me!